# How to set a starting point in a job?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

The transformation file, ending in .ktr, runs with no problem:

```
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Spoon - Transformation opened.
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Spoon - Launching transformation [FullCoverageTestCaseSalesMappingToReconciledSchema]...
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Spoon - Started the transformation execution.
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - FullCoverageTestCaseSalesMappingToReconciledSchema - Dispatching started for transformation [FullCoverageTestCaseSalesMappingToReconciledSchema]
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Reconciled.Weather.0 - Connected to database [Reconciled.Weather] (commit=1000)
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Reconciled.Sale.0 - Connected to database [ReconciledSchema] (commit=1000)
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Reconciled.IceCream.0 - Connected to database [ReconciledSchema] (commit=1000)
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - WeatherMapping.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - IceCreamMapping.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - WeatherMapping.0 - Finished processing (I=8, O=0, R=0, W=8, U=0, E=0)
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - IceCreamMapping.0 - Finished processing (I=7, O=0, R=0, W=7, U=0, E=0)
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Split Weather Text.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=8, W=8, U=0, E=0)
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Reconciled.Mapping.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Reconciled.Mapping.0 - Finished processing (I=6, O=0, R=0, W=6, U=0, E=0)
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Reconciled.IceCream.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=7, R=7, W=7, U=0, E=0)
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Reconciled.Sale.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=6, R=6, W=6, U=0, E=0)
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Reconciled.Weather.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=8, R=8, W=8, U=0, E=0)
2018/07/10 15:40:54 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
```

The job file, ending in .kjb, has only a reference to the above transformation file. It fails:

```
2018/07/10 15:34:35 - Spoon - Starting job...
2018/07/10 15:34:35 - Full Coverage Test Case - Start of job execution
2018/07/10 15:34:35 - Full Coverage Test Case - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : A serious error occurred during job execution: 
2018/07/10 15:34:35 - Full Coverage Test Case - Couldn't find starting point in this job.
2018/07/10 15:34:35 - Full Coverage Test Case - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleJobException: 
2018/07/10 15:34:35 - Full Coverage Test Case - Couldn't find starting point in this job.
2018/07/10 15:34:35 - Full Coverage Test Case - 
2018/07/10 15:34:35 - Full Coverage Test Case -     at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:532)
2018/07/10 15:34:35 - Full Coverage Test Case -     at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:436)
2018/07/10 15:34:35 - Spoon - Job has ended.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a Start thingy and connected it to the job thingy.That fixed it.
[image]

Comment: The "start thingy" is a "step", as the "transformation thingy" does too. Start Step -> Transformation Step.